# "General Error. General input/output error" when opening documents with Libreoffice

Tags: 14.04, libreoffice

I'm running LibreOffice 4.2.5.2 on Ubuntu 14.04. Trying to open any document (at first only with large ones, but now all of them) returns either of the messages below:

> General Error. General input/output error opening documents with Libreoffice

or

> Locked for editing by Unknown User

or

> The file is corrupt, should LibreOffice repair it?

LibreOffice 4.1.6, which came with the distribution upgrade, had the same bug.
Deleting the lock files (which I tried) does not fix it.

Sending the "corrupt" files to my email, I can preview their contents without problems.
I use LibreOffice only on Linux.

Comment: did you open file on samba share?

Comment: Good point, Letizia. Do you have write privileges in the folder of those files?

Answer (score 16):

This fixed the "General Error. General input/output error" problem for me after upgrading from Ubuntu 12.04 LTS to 16.04 LTS:

```
sudo apt install libreoffice
```

It seems like only a few of the LibreOffice packages were installed on the system after the upgrade. The above command installed some more of the packages.

Comment: This worked for me even on a new installation of 16.04 (not an upgrade).

Comment: Not worked for me in 17.10 64b

Comment: Had the input/output error only when opening a smb://nas.local... file, on a 18.04 upgraded from 17.04. Everything works after `sudo apt install libreoffice`, thanks a lot ;)

Comment: Wow. This worked for me even on Fedora: `dnf -y install libreoffice` solved this.

Answer (score 4):

I just received this same error message, after some digging I found that my `/tmp` partition was full. I freed some space in `/tmp` and could then open my spreadsheet.

**Note:** This will only be applicable if you use a `/tmp` partition - if you do not then it could be caused by your root partition being full but I'm guessing you will have other issues if that is the case.

Comment: Not working for Libreoffice 5.1.6.2

Answer (score 3):

I guess after all this time you either gave up or found another solution, but here is some input for others who may have the same issue.

I also got this "General Error. General input/output error" message, and found a solution on another forum:

Empty the contents of these two files:

```
~/.config/libreoffice/4/user/basic/dialog.xlc
~/.config/libreoffice/4/user/basic/script.xlc
```

One easy way to to it is running these commands in a terminal:

```
rm ~/.config/libreoffice/4/user/basic/dialog.xlc
rm ~/.config/libreoffice/4/user/basic/script.xlc
touch ~/.config/libreoffice/4/user/basic/dialog.xlc
touch ~/.config/libreoffice/4/user/basic/script.xlc
```

..or you could navigate to the files using Nautilus, open them in an editor, remove content and save. Your choice :)

After this, LibreOffice opened my file as if nothing had happened.

I believe if that doesn't work it is also an option to just delete the entire ~/.config/libreoffice/ folder, as I think it will be recreated, but I did not test that. Make a copy first if you want to try.

Comment: I'm running LibreOffice 4.4.2.2 and neither of these two (clearing the two files or removing the entire folder) worked for me.  I closed LibreOffice entirely, then performed the above actions, then started LibreOffice Calc and attempted to open a .xls file.  Upon completing the dialog that asks what character set to use for the import, I received the same general input/output error as before.  No change.

Comment: Sorry to hear that. I'm afraid I don't have any knowledge to add here. I just found a solution that worked in my case and shared it.

Comment: All good, and I don't mean to criticize your report.  I was just adding data from another experience of the same issue on a different system.  Fortunately I was able to solve the issue by uninstalling LibreOffice completely and reinstalling it.  I suspect that my recent 14.04 to 15.04 upgrade may have caused the problem.

Comment: Glad to hear that you got it working again :) After going through a series of release upgrades over the last years, my experience is that sometimes the best option is to go for a clean installation.

Comment: I almost always do.  Yet I also nearly always attempt the release-upgrade first just to see how well it will work.  In my experience since 09.10 they have gradually been getting better.  In this case I still have had no real need to clean-install 15.04, I only had to remove and freshly install LibreOffice.  But I'll be watching for any deeper troubles.

Comment: Not worked with Libreoffice 5.0.6.2

Answer (score 0):

Similar to [aweibell's last option](https://askubuntu.com/a/551334/26246) but through graphic interface.

1. Go to menu: Help → **Restart to safe mode**
2. Advanced → **Archive User Profile**, so you have a backup.
3. You may try partial reset steps but as last resolve, **Reset entire user profile**