# open excel xml in libreoffice calc

Tags: libreoffice

I need to open a 2.9MB excel xml file in LibreOffice Calc 5.1.4.2 but it fails, it gives the error message:

> General input/output error

I can open the same on my other machine (windows vista, libreoffice 4.2.1.1) without any problem, so the file is OK.

I have run

```
sudo apt install libreoffice
```

as suggested [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/770015/16726), but that didn't solve the issue.

any idea on how to solve this?

Comment: Have you tried [the other answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/551334/250300) at the linked page?

Comment: @Melebius yes, same result